# Graph: Compute shortest N paths with M max connections

Tags: .net, tree, nodes, shortest-path, dijkstra

VB.NET I am researching algorithms to compute shortest routes between points. I have read several articles and most mention [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). I've used this [.NET library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22647/Dijkstra-Shortest-Route-Calculation-Object-Oriente) in my project and it works fairly well.

I've studied the code and think I understand most of the logic. What I would like to do now is be able to do the following:

- Limit the search to a max of M connections or paths. A driver may be willing to make, say, only 2 connections max.
- Return not only the shortest route between point A and point B but also the N shortest routes. A driver may want to consider some alternative routes.

Are these two options possible? The request is for any links on pre-existing libraries that can do this or guidance on how I can go about tweaking the current library to achieve the two options.

We have trips in our system with cities and connections. We also compute a weight based on distance and cost. My data looks like so:

Cities:

[image]

Connections:

[image]

Update: Using [Eric Lippert's implementation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/10/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-four/) as re-used by [Leniel](https://www.leniel.net/2009/06/astar-pathfinding-search-in-csharp.html) I was able to tweak the code to get a list of alternative paths. The user can then take this class and order it by a field and take only the top N or bottom N depending on what they want as a result. I think this answers question #2.

In the Path class I added a new field

```
public class Path<Node> : IEnumerable<Path<Node>> {
    public List<Path<Node>> AltRoutes { get; set; }
```

In the Astar.FindPath function I modified this snippet

```
    if (path.LastStep.Equals(destination))
    {
        var altRoutes = GetAlternativePaths(queue, estimate, origin, destination);
        path.AltRoutes = altRoutes;
        return path;
    }
```

and based on the existing sub ViewOtherPaths I created this function to get alternative paths from the queue

```
    private static List<Path<TNode>> GetAlternativePaths<TNode>(PriorityQueue<double, Path<TNode>> queue, Func<TNode, double> estimate, TNode origin, TNode destination)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPossible paths:\n");

        //this will hold all the alternative routes from origin to destination
        List<Path<TNode>> altRoutes = new List<Path<TNode>>();

        // The priority queue is composed of KeyValuePairs which has as key a double value (the TotalCost) and
        // has as Value a Queue which contains Paths.
        foreach (KeyValuePair<double, Queue<Path<TNode>>> kvp in queue)
        {
            // For each path in the Queue...
            foreach (Path<TNode> otherPath in kvp.Value)
            {
                // Reverse the Path so that we get the order of the cities in a more meaningful way...
                var otherPathReversed = otherPath.Cast<Path<Node>>().Reverse();

                var firstSeg = otherPathReversed.ToList().Find(x => x.PreviousSteps != null);
                var lastSeg = otherPathReversed.Last();
                var rtFrom = firstSeg.PreviousSteps.LastStep.Key;
                var rtTo = lastSeg.LastStep.Key;

                if (firstSeg.PreviousSteps.LastStep.Equals(origin) && lastSeg.LastStep.Equals(destination))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Routing from {0} to {1}", rtFrom, rtTo);
                    altRoutes.Add(otherPath);

                    // Prints on screen the Cities that are part of this path.
                    foreach (Path<Node> path in otherPathReversed)
                    {
                        if (path.PreviousSteps != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("  Path from {0, -14} to {1, -14} -> Total cost = {2:#.###} {3}",
                                              path.PreviousSteps.LastStep.Key, path.LastStep.Key, path.TotalCost, DistanceType.Kilometers));
                        }
                    }

                    // Get the estimation cost of the other possible path.
                    double otherPathEstimation = estimate(otherPath.LastStep);

                    // Prints on the screen the relevant information so that it gets easier to debug the code and see how
                    // the A* search algorithm really does the job...
                    Console.WriteLine("Estimation          = {0:0.###} {1}", otherPathEstimation, DistanceType.Kilometers);
                    Console.WriteLine("Priority Queue Cost = {0:0.###} {1} = (Total cost + Estimation)", kvp.Key, DistanceType.Kilometers);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }

        return altRoutes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Limit the search to a max of M connections or paths. A driver may be willing to make, say, only 2 connections max.

Set search depth x, in this case 2.

2) Return not only the shortest route between point A and point B but also the N shortest routes. A driver may want to consider some alternative routes.

.Take(x)

---

Let say you have implemented an interface

```
Public Interface IProblem(Of T)
    Function GetRoot() As INode(Of T)
    Function IsGoal(ByVal current As INode(Of T)) As Boolean
    Function GetStepCost(ByVal current As INode(Of T), ByVal [next] As T) As Double
    Function GetSuccessors(ByVal current As INode(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of INode(Of T))
    Function GetHeuristicValue(ByVal [next] As T) As Double
End Interface
```

Now typically you would use a data structure that efficiently keeps items in order, like a priority queue ex: [Eric Lippert's implementation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/astar/). But this is more efficient if you want to limit the heuristically function cost rather than depth. For example depth 3 element path can be lower than any Depth 2 element paths.

The root node will have depth 0 and when you traverse is connections by GetSuccessors you set depth +1. In the search method, check for depth and instead of IPriorityQueue you can use a normal Queue.

```
Public Function Search(
    ByVal problem As IProblem(Of T), 
    ByVal fringe As IPriorityQueue(Of INode(Of T)),
    ByVal depth As Integer
) As IEnumerable(IEnumerable(Of INode(Of T)))
    Dim node As INode(Of T)
    fringe.Add(problem.GetRoot())

    While !fringe.IsEmpty
        node = fringe.DeleteMin()
        If node.Depth > x Then Continue While
        If problem.IsGoal(node) Then Yield Util.GetPathFromRoot(node)
        fringe.AddAll(problem.GetSuccessors(node))
    End While

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The Util.GetPathFromRoot just traverses the node to parent until it reaches node that has no parent and adds them to collection, for easier use - you can just return the node as well. So lets say node is:

```
Public Interface INode(Of Out T)
    ReadOnly Property State As T
    ReadOnly Property Parent As INode(Of T)
    ReadOnly Property IsRootNode As Boolean
    ReadOnly Property StepCost As Double
    ReadOnly Property PathCost As Double
    ReadOnly Property Action As String
End Interface
```

After that you can use a lambda query to limit the results. However if you do not use priority queue then here you should order them by Path cost.

```
Dim xResults = results.OrderBy(Function(node) node.First().PathCost).Take(x).ToList()
```

Comment: In this example what represents the points and what represents the connections?

Comment: A node is a generic object that contains the State. The state in this case would be the point, containing properties like {Name, Location point(x, y)}. The GetSuccessors method is responsible of returning all the valid connections from that node. In your case, you could add {Id, List of Connection Id's} to state. Where Id is unique identifier or reuse point name. GetSuccessors should have a visibility to see all nodes to quickly filter just ones that are in list of connection id's for that node.

Comment: I meant to say "List of tuples containing Connection Id's and weight" as usually StepCost is an alternative weight value returned by the heuristics function for example Euclidean distance from city locations points. A* uses heuristics function and if it is chosen correctly then usually result exceeds 95% quantile of optimal solution.

Comment: Using Eric Lippert's implementation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/10/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-four/ as written by 
leniel https://www.leniel.net/2009/06/astar-pathfinding-search-in-csharp.html.For the depth as you suggested I have added                 if(closed.Contains(path.LastStep))
                    continue; 
if(path.Count() > 2) continue;
 Will that be the proper place to put the while loop break?

Comment: @sinDizzy in this example data you had 4 nodes and 6 connections, as your input data amount grows then speed improvements become more important. You can do that, however a larger effect would be from moving .Take to before .OrderBy.

Comment: I have way more than that in my actual data: 201 points, 1111 connections. Right now I am concentrating on the max depth. Based on Lippert's function FindPath() I place the depth check after the check for path.LastStep. Do you think that is the appropriate place?

Comment: @sinDizzy yes, it seems fine.

Comment: So the MaxDepth didn't quite work but the alternative paths...I think I got something to work. Please review my edit in the OP when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

of cause you can, let say you got some city a, b, c, d ... and a matrix of distance between them like

```
    a   b   c   d ...
a   0   2   7   1 ...
b   2   0   5   9 ...
c...
```

then, you know Dis2 = Dis x Dis(where Dis1[i, j] = min(Dis[i, k] + Dis[k, j]) ) is the distance matrix where at most two path visited. so Dis^M is the distance matrix where at most M path visited.

after that, you want to give more than shortest path. you can save N shortest path at every Dis[i, j] and the multiply become N path join another N path and save the shortest N path. see you got it